How do I calculate the flux passing through a closed cone (with charge placed at vertex) with Gauss Law?
I know that for a point charge placed at the vertex of a cone, the formula for flux passing through the (closed) cone will be equal to :-

$\phi$ = $\frac{q}{2\epsilon_0}\times[1-cos\theta]$ where $\theta$ is the semi vertical angle of the cone.

Now , I know the derivation of this flux without using Gauss law , and that method involves integration which I have learnt.
However I am wondering if I can derive the same formula using Gauss Law.  I will have to somehow bring the charge q(placed at the vertex) at the centre of the gaussian surface I will consider, but I have no idea if this can be done in a simple way using gauss law.
I first thought that I should consider a sphere with charge present at the centre and cone being inside it , but clearly that does not work out...I guess.
Basically I am really blank about how to get this started.... so can anyone help me out?


I would never say "never", but you may end up having problems making this notion mathematically well-defined due to the divergence of the electric field at the location of the charge.  That said, I have a vague recollection that Zangwill discusses this issue in an early chapter;  if I have time in the coming week I'll loop back & post about it.

ok thank youu :)
